# Cascading Combobox in extjs

Tags: javascript, spring, hibernate, extjs

I want to do cascading combobox in extjs. I have to comboboxes

**Course combobox**

```
{ 
    xtype : 'combobox',  
    emptyText : 'Course',  
    id:'combo-course',  
    displayField : 'name',  
    valueField : 'id',  
    store:coursestore,  
    forceSelection: true,  
    triggerAction:'all',  
    queryMode: 'remote',  
    listeners: {  
        'select': {  
            fn:function(combo, value) {  
                var comboModule = Ext.getCmp('combo-module');  
                comboModule .setDisabled(true);
        comboModule .clearValue('');
        comboModule .getStore().removeAll();
        comboModule .getStore().load({
        params: {courseId: combo.getValue()}
         });
                comboModule .setDisabled(false);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**Course-Module:**

```
{
    xtype : 'combobox',  
    emptyText : 'Module',  
    id:'combo-module',  
    displayField : 'name',  
    valueField : 'id',  
    disabled:true,  
    remoteFilter:true,  
    store:coursemodulestore,  
    forceSelection: true,  
    queryMode: 'remote',  
    triggerAction:'all'
}
```

**Rest Service**

```
    @Path("/coursemodule/{courseId}")
    public List<CourseModule> getAllCourseModules(@PathParam("courseId")String courseId ) {
        try {           
            return courseObj.getModulesForCourse(courseId);
                } catch (HibernateException e) {
            logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I am running the application and select the first combobox it shows the right values in second combobox in the first time only;
But when I am selecting the combobox the second time its not displaying values in second combobox.

Comment: omg.. highly unreadable.... give us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please

Comment: Try to keep the formatting when editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to clear the filter you already applied.  To remove filters that have been applied there is a clearFilter() method available on the store.  You can mix that into your code similar to this:

```
comboModule.clearValue();  
// new line to clear any filter applied to the store
comboModule.getStore().clearFilter(true);  
comboModule.getStore().filter('courseId',combo.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your issue is that the store.load() is async.
Try passing in the rest of your logic (filtering etc) in the callback of load.

Answer (score 0):

Is it showing a LoadMask the second time you load it?

Use this to override that behaviour:

```
Ext.override(Ext.LoadMask, {
    onHide: function() {
    this.callParent();
  }
});
```