# Dynamically Loading data when performing cascading in comboboxes in extjs

Tags: extjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cascading Combobox in extjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193361/cascading-combobox-in-extjs)

Hi I have two comboboxes ,viz..

**AcademicClass**

```
{
    xtype : 'combobox',
    emptyText : 'Academic Class',
    displayField : 'name',
    id:'comboacademicclass',
    valueField : 'id',
    store:classstore,
    triggerAction:'all',
    mode:'local',
    listeners : {
        'select' : {
            fn: function(combo1, value) {
                var comboSubject=Ext.getCmp('combo-subject');
                var classId=Ext.getCmp('comboacademicclass').getValue();
                comboSubject.setDisabled(true);
                comboSubject.setValue('');
                comboSubject.getStore().removeAll(true);
                comboSubject.getStore().load({url:'http://localhost:8080/WebService/rest/type/academicSubjectByClass/'+classId+'.json'});
                    // Using this loading data in second combobox by passing first combobox Id.:- 'classId'.
                    comboSubject.setDisabled(false); 
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**AcademicSubject**:

```
{
    xtype : 'combobox',
    emptyText : 'Academic Subject',
    id:'combo-subject',
    displayField : 'name',
    valueField : 'id',
    disabled:true,
    store:subjectstore,
    triggerAction:'all',
    mode:'local'
    ,lastQuery:''
}
```

Its showing output only first time selection but on second time selection its just showing "Loading" and not dispalying output. Please Help.

Comment: Please tell us the version? 2.x, 3.x or 4.x

Answer (score 1):

Well you should listen with the AcademicSubject combo on the AcademicClass for the `select` or the `change` event and activate the listening combo along with it. You will also get the selected value and can so prepare the query for the activate combo. You could do this like

```
combobox.queryData = [{ property: 'fieldName', value: value}];
combobox.reset();
combobox.doQuery(combobox.queryData);
```

where `combobox` is a reference to the activated combo (AcademicSubject ) and `value` a propertyvalue from the AcademicClass combo. To ensure the use of your new query use

```
combobox.on('beforequery', function (e) {
    e.query = e.combo.queryData;
});
```

Please note:
For the snippets above I recommend to use `queryParam: 'filter'` which would enable you to use default serverside filter behavior without the need to introduce a new param.